# Error al llamar API desde JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, api

Estoy teniendo problemas al llamar un api desde JS, les adjunto el código, espero puedan ayudarme, no hace nada, me manda directamente a la accion de error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var datos = JSON.stringify({
        to: "cesar.villasenor@servidor.com",
        cc: "",
        bcc: "",
        ishtml: "True",
        headercolor: "#F40059",
        subject: "Alerta de Baja de producto",
        title: "IT Inventory",
        message: "Se ha dado de baja un producto",
        width:"1800px"
    });
    $.ajax({
    URL: 'http://servidor/services/email/api/email',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: datos,
    success: function (data, status, xhr){
    alert("Email Enviado!");
        },
    error: function (xhr, status, error){
    alert("Error al Enviar!");
        }
    });
    alert("Registro guardado exitosamente");
    window.location.href='index.php';
</script>
```

Comment: Hola bienvenido a StackOverFlow te invito a realizar el [tour] para que comprendas como funciona el sitio y así obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). También te invito a revisar [ask]. Podrías especificar que error tienes?

Comment: Por seguridad, solamente se pueden enviar peticiones Ajax al mismo servidor de la página, te recomiendo que en tu servidor hagas un cliente de la API externa para poder ejecutar las peticiones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que tal Cesar en las propiedades del $.ajax, suprime las propiedades de:

contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',

Ya que no las requiere la API para procesar tu petición:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var datos = JSON.stringify({
        to: "cesar.villasenor@servidor.com",
        cc: "",
        bcc: "",
        ishtml: "True",
        headercolor: "#F40059",
        subject: "Alerta de Baja de producto",
        title: "IT Inventory",
        message: "Se ha dado de baja un producto",
        width:"1800px"
    });
    $.ajax({
    URL: 'http://servidor/services/email/api/email',
    type: 'POST',
    data: datos,
    success: function (data, status, xhr){
        console.log(xhr);
        alert("Email Enviado!");

        },
    error: function (xhr, status, error){
        console.log(status);
        alert("Error al Enviar!");
        }
    });
    alert("Registro guardado exitosamente");
    window.location.href='index.php';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Como una observación el alert de "Registro guardado ... " deberias mandarlo dentro del success ya que haces una petición asincrona de primera instancia, y no sabes cuanto puede tardar en responder la API

[image: Mira el resultado]

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya no me arroja error, sigue sin mandarme el correo pero hace la accion del success, espero sea error del api jeje

Comment: Te invito a que marques la respuesta como finalizada , la parte del correo, validen que su servicio de SMTP se haya programado correctamente , ya que en la API no vi que controlen mensajes de respuesta , solo los "status", saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Quiero creer que tu api termina con extension .php, entonces solo es necesario poner esa termnacion y no es necesario poner toda la direccion de carpeta, quedaria algo asi..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var datos = JSON.stringify({
        to: "cesar.villasenor@servidor.com",
        cc: "",
        bcc: "",
        ishtml: "True",
        headercolor: "#F40059",
        subject: "Alerta de Baja de producto",
        title: "IT Inventory",
        message: "Se ha dado de baja un producto",
        width:"1800px"
    });
    $.ajax({
    URL: 'api/email.php',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: datos,
    success: function (data, status, xhr){
    alert("Email Enviado!");
        },
    error: function (xhr, status, error){
    alert("Error al Enviar!");
        }
    });
    alert("Registro guardado exitosamente");
    window.location.href='index.php';
</script>
```

Comment: La zona de respuetas no es espacio para suponer o creer, deberías dejarle esta pregunta en la zona de comentarios y con base en ello responder